# Pointer before Malloc

Tags: c

what is different between this:

`tElemPtr novyPrvok = (tElemPtr *)malloc(sizeof(tElemPtr));`

and this:

`tElemPtr novyPrvok = malloc(sizeof(tElemPtr));`

I want to use it in InsertFirst function for inserting first element in the beginning of the List. Because, if I use without that pointer in front of malloc, Xcode tells me it is good, but I cant use "novyPrvok->data"

```
void InsertFirst (tList *L, int val) {  
    tElemPtr novyPrvok = (tElemPtr *)malloc(sizeof(tElemPtr));

    if(novyPrvok == NULL)
        Error();

    novyPrvok->data = val;
    novyPrvok->ptr = L->First;
    L->First = novyPrvok;              
}
```

Comment: you meant     tElemPtr *novyPrvok = (tElemPtr *)malloc(sizeof(tElemPtr)); ?

Comment: @OznOg tElemPtr - it is probably typedef-ed pointer.

Comment: show *failing* code and exact error message

Comment: then the cast and the sizeof() are wrong

Comment: typedefing pointers is a horrible habit, leading to difficult to read code. Do bot do it. The only exeption: function pointers

Comment: @P__J__ Function pointers are no exception. If you don't like the syntax, you can just typedef functions.

Comment: Casting malloc()'s return value is not something that needs to be, or should be, done. http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

Comment: @melpomene function pointers are usually used another way then the "normal" pointers.

Comment: @Shawn it is a prehistoric opinion. C standard does not allow functions with no prototypes (it is the error now not the warning - and you cant compile the code the program with no <stdlib.h> included ), so that link is about 20years outdated. Obsolete opinion. Now it only question of taste

Comment: They are similar in a way that neither former nor the latter makes any sense. Check your indirection levels carefully.

Comment: @P__J__ You'll find that many compilers, including gcc and clang, will complain about it but still compile programs that use malloc without including the appropriate header.

Comment: @Shawn just use the correct compile option to set the modern language standard.

Comment: @P__J__ Even with C11 (Which is the default in recent versions of gcc, not sure about clang), they will compile such code. Don't believe me? Try it yourself with a file with nothing but `int main(void) { int *x = malloc(sizeof *x); }` in it and compile with `gcc -std=c11`. You'll get some warnings, but it *will* compile (Tested with gcc 7 and 8, and clang 6). If that's not enough to demonstrate that, yes, compilers still let you use functions without declaring them first, well... I'm done. Peace.

Comment: hi, please can you tell me, how can I acces data, when I have it declared linke pointer? (*tElemPtr)


typedef struct tElem {
    struct tElem *ptr;
    int data;
} *tElemPtr;
                                                           

typedef struct {
    tElemPtr Act;
    tElemPtr First;}
 tList;

Answer (score 1):

no need to cast malloc return -> [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1)

BTW your code seems wrong; as tElemPtr seems to be a typedef on a pointer, I would expect the malloc to be:

```
tElemPtr novyPrvok = malloc(sizeof(*novyPrvok));
```

Comment: No need for `()`.  Could use `sizeof *novyPrvok` instead of `sizeof(*novyPrvok)`.

Answer (score -1):

your malloc is wrong, its only allocating space for a pointer. After that everything is Undefined Behavior. Should be

```
 tElemPtr novyPrvok = (tElemPtr *)malloc(sizeof(*tElemPtr));
```

Comment: You're right, but the code sample isn't. `tElemPtr novyPrvok = malloc(sizeof *novyPrvok);`

Comment: You're still only allocating space for a pointer. Or at least you would be if `*tElemPtr` wasn't a syntax error.